# WCF Data Services - Including children on first request

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have an entity model with a sales line and a multiple line items.  When I do a request for a particular line, I get the line information back, but I don't get an of the children line items back.  I've tried removing the  [XmlIgnoreAttribute()] and [SoapIgnoreAttribute()] from the navigation property but I still don't get the child items.  Can WCF Data Services not serialize an entire object graph in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you must say service that you want to load navigation property as well by using [Expand extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx) on client.